# PHP url decode does not work

Tags: php, urldecode

I have issue in decoding a url received from an iOS app; the url is of th kind:

> percorsoWithOption.php?partenza=Via%20Gaspare%20Balbi%202–8&arrivo=Via%20Conca%20d'Oro&language=it_IT&latitude=41.717835&longitude=12.311369&endLatitude=41.679623&endLongitude=12.484474&json=1

and when I try to decode it at the following:
[Online decoder](https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/urldecode/)
it is decoded just fine.
Yet when I apply:

```
if (isset($_GET['arrivo'])) $arrivo=$_GET['arrivo'];
if (isset($_GET['partenza'])) $partenza=$_GET['partenza'];
error_log("*inizio**departure=$partenza, arrival=$arrivo,   latitude=$latitude, longitude=$longitude");
if (isset($partenza)) $partenza=urldecode($partenza);
if (isset($arrivo)) $arrivo=urldecode($arrivo);
error_log("***departure=$partenza, arrival=$arrivo, latitude=$latitude, longitude=$longitude");
```

the logs report the values nearly unchanged:

> [Tue Dec 01 12:25:22.566615 2015] [:error] [pid 20812] [client
>   82.61.145.186:37526] *inizio**departure=Via Gaspare Balbi 2\xe2\x80\x938, arrival=Via Conca d'Oro, latitude=41.717835,
>   longitude=12.311369 [Tue Dec 01 12:25:22.569876 2015] 
>   [:error] [pid 20812] [client 82.61.145.186:37526] ***departure=Via Gaspare Balbi
>   2\xe2\x80\x938, arrival=Via Conca d'Oro, latitude=41.717835,
>   longitude=12.311369
>   basically the 2\xe2\x80\x938 is left untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
-(NSString*)stripNonStandardAndEncode:(NSString*)origin{
     NSMutableCharacterSet *charactersToKeep = [NSMutableCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
    [charactersToKeep addCharactersInString:@" ,.'"];

    NSCharacterSet *charactersToRemove = [charactersToKeep invertedSet];

    NSString *trimmedReplacement = [[ origin componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charactersToRemove] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [trimmedReplacement stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

And now php handles it seamlessly: url decode may have some issue with character '-'

Answer (score 0):

It's not "nearly unchanged", it's URL-decoding just fine. The only issue is that the *en dash* is showing up as "\xe2\x80\x93" in your log.

1. It's unclear whether this is an issue of how values are logged or viewed, or whether the value is *actually* "\xe2\x80\x93". To test this, use `bin2hex()` on your string and see whether it shows up as `e28093` (just the – character)  or `5c78...` (literally "\x...").
2. That en dash should be sent URL-encoded as `%E2%80%93` in the URL, not as the raw character. Fix this on the client.

Comment: I encode the string in objective c with simple:
[start stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
I also tried a string extension on the web with the same result.

Comment: Can't tell you how to do it correctly in ObjC, that'd need to be a separate question.

Comment: I wrote it, it is quite standard.

Comment: What I can advise you is to check whether it's merely a problem of your logging, or whether your value is *actually* strangely decoded to `\x..`.

Comment: I even tried:
[start stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
with the same produced url. The strange issue is that :
https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/urldecode/
decodes all of them, as you may try yourself. This hinting to a problem with the php support.

Comment: Have. You. Tried. `bin2hex`?!

Comment: Where? In objective c or php?!
A a matter of fact I am thinking of stripping all characters different from spaces and hyphens.

Comment: In PHP, for debugging the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [rawurldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) function.

Comment: Unfortunately the 2\xe2\x80\x938 remains unchanged even with rawurldecode